# How to implement Live notification using PHP,MYSQL,AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm developing a monitoring tool, it have a shift handover process

1.when current user reday hit hanover button it ask's the person name to handover shift
2.then the entry is added to mysql table(handover request table).

here the php should notify who has a request on database, it's possible by AJAX set interval, but i want when the request is in DATABASE that should be notify on user interface(by loged session name), please suggest codes or ideas